# My object is not recognizing the key that is already been set

Tags: javascript, object, qualtrics

I have this snippet of code (unfortunately it won't work for you unless you have a qualtrics account and go into preview survey and run it in the console) that keeps throwing the error (Cannot set property 'questions0' of undefined). Yet I just added an object named ArrayOfBlocks2 to the main object. Can someone tell my why its saying ArrayOfBlocks2 is undefined?

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("ArrayOfBlocks",ArrayOfBlocks)
var ArrayOfBlocks1 = Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData("ArrayOfBlocks")
for(i=0;i<Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData("ArrayOfBlocks").length;i++){
    for(k=0;k<Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData("ArrayOfBlocks")[i].BlockElements.length;k++){
        var ArrayOfBlocks2 = ArrayOfBlocks1[i].ID
        console.log(ArrayOfBlocks2)
        ObjectIDWithQuestions[ArrayOfBlocks2]={}
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("OBID",ObjectIDWithQuestions);
        ObjectIDWithQuestions.ArrayOfBlocks2["questions"+ k]=Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData("ArrayOfBlocks")[i].BlockElements[k].QuestionID
            Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("ObjectIDWithQuestions",ObjectIDWithQuestions)

    }
}
```

I expect it to not throw an error, and to set "questions + k" as a object key.

Comment: It looks like that nested for needs to `getEmbeddedData(...)[k]` , not `[i]`. Am I reading it right? Or your `'questions' + k` needs to be `'questions' + i`. Would be my guess.

Answer (score 0):

Embedded data won't store an array by default, you will likely need to json encode the data before storing, and json parse the data on retrieval.

Comment: Actually, you can store almost anything in embedded data including arrays, objects, whatever! It’s actually a pretty cool part of Qualtrics